# RStudio code-folding behaving oddly?

Tags: rstudio, folding

Does this fold as expected? If so, why? For me, the lines with "<" fold multiple sections. I've looked at RStudio folding documentation (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections) but this behavior is not explained.

```
test<-iris
#----
test1<-iris$Sepal.Length <0
#----
test2<-iris$Sepal.Width < 0
#----
test3<-iris$Petal.Length >0
#----
test4<-iris$Petal.Width > 1
#----
test5<-iris$Petal.Width
```

Comment: RStudio? working fine . Platform: 64 Bit Ubuntu . RStudio 0.99.485

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with RStudio v1.0.44; we'll try to get to the bottom of this!